# groovy create closure programmatically

Tags: groovy, closures

How to create `closure` programmatically?

I mean not like this

```
def closure = { println "hello world" }
```

but more like this

```
Closure cl = new MethodClosure(this, "method")
....
```

and then call different methods of the closure to define body and etc.

Comment: Why? Just wondering. There may be a better solution

Comment: @tim_yates  Pure academic. Because it should be possible to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your example is not actually of creating a Closure programmatically because it basically requires parsing and compiling the method's *source code* into a Closure. The *parsing* being the problem. Creating a Closure programmatically would look similar to an implementation of a Groovy AST transformation; you'd be manipulating objects which represent low-level language constructs. In pseudo-code... things like IfStatement, ClosureLiteral, MethodCall, etc. Then you'd compile this into objects; essentially by-passing source code parsing. It's kind of like the difference between a String containing a query, and a query builder like Grail's GORM.

However, Groovy does provide an easy way to do what you're looking for in your example using the `Eval` class. Here's an example:

```
Closure closure = Eval.me("{ a, b -> a * b }")

assert closure instanceof Closure
assert closure(2, 3) == 6
```

Comment: With all the usual warning stickers about evaluating user input as code